# Databinding class not generated for multiple layout folders

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-studio-3.6, android-sourcesets

In Android studio 3.6, after creating new project, I am not able to created binding generated class for multiple folders.

I have multiple layout folders:

```
res/layout
res/layouts/dashboard
res/layouts/notifications
```

I am able to created binding class for

> res/layout

but its not working for other layout folders.

App gradle file:

```
dataBinding{
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs =
                    [
                            'src/main/res/layouts/notification',
                            'src/main/res/layout/dashboard',
                            'src/main/res/layouts',
                            'src/main/res/layout',
                            'src/main/res'
                    ]
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
        }
    }
```

Resource folder structure:

[image]

I have attached sample project which I have created in android studio 3.6.
[Source code link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqdfc5na5xdjzqf/MyApplication.zip)

Comment: We are facing the same issue.

Comment: Still looking for such solutions

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in android studio, It has been fixed in android studio 4.0 beta and 4.1 canary. And google will release hotfix for 3.6 to fix it.

Comment: Is there an issue you can link to? I'm using ViewBinding on 3.6.1 and the the binding classes are being generated, but the linter is unable to recognize them

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix until this is fixed in Android Studio:

Add the output of the generated binding files to your gradle file (this works for both view binding and data binding):

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += 'build/generated/data_binding_base_class_source_out/debug/out'## Heading ##
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60521114/792853