# How to initialize ViewBinding?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to initialize VievBinding? In AppCompactActivity version 1.0.0, it became possible to pass a layout to the parent constructor so that you would not write OnCreateView.
I do so, but then I want to use VievBinding, but it doesn’t work for me. Text is not displayed. What can be done?

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        var binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.hello.text = "Hello"
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: I read. If you OnCreateView, then everything will work. But I don’t need that. I would like to know how to re-initialize ViewBinding.

Comment: Why is it in `onStart` instead of `onCreate`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.bind(findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).getChildAt(0))
    }
```

Although it's easier if you rely on `__Binding.inflate()`.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.activity_main)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
```

Layout inflation should not be in `onStart`. It goes in `onCreate` in Activity, and `onCreateView` in Fragment.

Comment: Yes it would be easier. But I need to make BaseActivity, and that all Activity would be inherited from it.

Comment: I don't understand how that changes anything in what I said?

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.bind(findViewById(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT))
    }

Comment: Not work  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I'll change my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Activity class
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   val binding:YourActivityLayoutBinding = 
         DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_activity_layout);
}
```

Layout views in xml should be surrounded by `<layout>` tag

```
<layout>
...// your activity view layout
</layout>
```

Comment: The question is for view binding, and not for databinding

Comment: val binding:YourActivityLayoutBinding is the viewbinding

Comment: actually ```DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_activity_layout)``` returns view binding

Comment: OK, sorry I got you, setContentView can be called through DataBindingUtil
but its actially returns viewbinding

Comment: Not sure why people down voted this. But the info here is useful. I ran into this same issue and was fixed by:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147214/view-binding-not-work-with-include-incompatible-types-progressbarlayoutbindi/59009142#59009142

Answer (score 0):

**var binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)**

This will inflate the layout again and you will get a different instance of the views than what is already set in the activity

Try using the below code to bind the activity view to the binder. Where ROOT_VIEW_ID is view id of root view in your layout

**var binding = ActivityMainBinding.bind(findViewById(ROOT_VIEW_ID))***
***binding.hello.text = "Hello"**